# whats the difference between those links?

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, .aspxauth

link 1 = https://website.com/ %D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D

link 2 = https://website.com/q.aspx?q= %D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D

whats the difference and how they work, please.

and if you familiar with it let me know. PM for co-working.

p.s Im not a developer so need your best knowledge guys.

thanks.

Comment: Is this is quiz for us? They're obviously different, so what else do you want to know?

Comment: This is something only "website.com" can answer. I'm voting to close this question because questions about external sites aren't on-topic on StackOverflow. See [help/on-topic] for what topics you can ask about here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Link1 : https://website.com/<abc>
```

> Here <abc> is generally considered the sub-category of the hierarchy of the website in the URL.
>  For ex : https://website.com/user/settings

```
Link2 : https://website.com/q.aspx?q=<abc>
```

> `?q=` term stands for query ,i.e. it is used when searching & loading data on the page where main term is <abc>. 
> In this case, `q.aspx` page is being loaded where query term is <abc> 
> For ex. : https://website.com/q.aspx?q=latest_products 
>  Also note q can be any other variable, which is then accessed on the backend by the code in q.aspx file, for ex : https://website.com/q.aspx?mytopic=latest_products

Comment: This small read might help understand the basic format of a URL 
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/html-url.php